# Host Swagger documentation with SpringDoc with yaml files

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc

I found a pretty neat link to host yaml files in Swagger UI [here](https://songrgg.github.io/operation/host-swagger-documentation-with-yaml-json-files/), but it uses Springfox instead of Springdoc so I would like to know if there is any other equivalent way of doing it since my company would prefer the latter.

I would really appreciate any help, just a guide is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can watch [this](https://springdoc.org/) project. As I understand it, they can use static content.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the documentation:

- https://springdoc.org/faq.html#what-is-a-proper-way-to-set-up-swagger-ui-to-use-provided-specyml